# Notation problem for differential of a function

Tags: calculus

In the book 'Advanced calculus of several variables' by C.H. Edwards I came across the following:

(1)"Since S is a linear mapping it holds that $dS_{x}=S...$"

(2)"Let f be some mapping with $f'(0)=I$ (the n$\times$n  identity matrix... note that since $df_{0}=I$..."

I am somewhat confused by this notation; I know that for a differential of an arbitrary function $g$ at point $a$ we have $dg_{a}=g'(a)x$. If I now apply this to (1) and (2) I would get for (1) that $dS_{x}(x)=S(x)=M_{S}x$ where $M_{S}$ is the matrix of the linear mapping, by the definition of a linear function . If I would do the same for (2) I would get $df_{0}(x)=I(x)=I$ since the identity matrix is constant. But I think what is meant is $df_{0}(x)=Ix$ since $f'(0)=I$.

How do I know in general what is meant? Am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct: if $df_{0} = I$, then applying this linear transformation to a vector $x$ (tangent to the domain of your function at $0$) gives $df_{0}(x) = Ix = x$.

To get a clear and intuitive explanation of differentials, check out Arnol'd's "Ordinary Differential Equations," a latest edition.  In a nutshell, function differentials are linear transformations on the tangent spaces of your function's domain.